# Nullpointer setadapter in spinner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, spinner

this is my code where there is an error.
i think that every its ok but i dont know where is the error
this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
private EditText promAcum;
private EditText credCur;
private EditText sem;
private EditText num_examenes;
private EditText editText13;
private EditText editText14;
private EditText editText15;
private EditText editText16;
private EditText editText17;
private EditText editText18;
private EditText editText19;
private EditText editText20;
private EditText editText21;
private Spinner spinner1;
public String valorPromAcum;
public String valorCredCur;
public String valorSem;
public String[] numeroExamenes={"3","4","5","6"};
private final static String TAG_FRAGMENT = "TAG_FRAGMENT";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);

    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new MainFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }

    promAcum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.promAcum);
    credCur = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credCur);
    sem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sem);
    editText13 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    editText14 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    editText15 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    editText16 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText16);
    editText17 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText17);
    editText18 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText18);
    editText19 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText19);
    editText20 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText20);
    editText21 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText21);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,numeroExamenes);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

                int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "On Button Click : " + 
                        "\n" + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });}
```

this is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/materias"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="text" >

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/creditos"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="30sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad de Examenes"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Examen" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Nota" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="%" />

        </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>  

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </TableRow>

 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/guardar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:onClick="agregarNotas"
        android:text="@string/materias" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/nueva" />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat error line 78 : spinner1.setadapter(adapter);

```
enter code here09-03 11:25:46.344: E/AndroidRuntime(7841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 11:25:46.344: E/AndroidRuntime(7841): at com.jonathanar.promapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
```

any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: is the post xml name `activity_main`. If not the views probably belong to Fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve Views from `Activity`, but they are in `Fragment`.

`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourId);` is what you should do whenever you are using `findViewById()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is not a problem with instantiating your adapter, but rather with the way you are getting the Spinner.

If the spinner exists in the fragment you need to specify its context as so.

just putting findViewById() is really this.findViewById(), where this is your activity. In other words your telling the method to find views in the content view of the activity.

If the spinner is in the content view of the fragment, you need to instead use

```
fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.???);
```

this way findViewById() knows to find your spinner in the context of the fragment.

Hope this helps!